# call an activity inside another activity using PAF

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I'm trying to include one activity inside another. Is it possible to call an activity inside another activity using Pace Automation Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel Thread feature will allow you to call an activity inside another activity so we can run the activity parallel to it.

Call the Activity from the same activity xml file - PAF ALM integration works for the scenario. The tags inside the activity would call the parallel thread using the attribute parallel_thread=”activity id”